# Access-Control-Allow-Origin in ajax call to jersey rest web services

Tags: java, ajax, json, rest, cors

I used jersey JAX-Rs as web service to query mysql.I try to consume the web-service via hybrid mobile application .

I refer this 
http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/11/building-restful-services-with-java-using-jax-rs-and-jersey-sample-application/#comment-440541

In server side the following code running in tomcat server7 to query sql

```
@Path("/employees")
 public class EmployeeResource {

EmployeeDAO dao = new EmployeeDAO();

@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public List<Employee> findAll() {
    return dao.findAll();
}
}
```

public class EmployeeDAO {

```
public List<Employee> findAll() {
    List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    Connection c = null;
String sql = "SELECT e.id, e.firstName, e.lastName, e.title FROM employee as e";

    try {
        c = ConnectionHelper.getConnection();
        Statement s = c.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            list.add(processSummaryRow(rs));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        ConnectionHelper.close(c);
    }
    return list;
}

protected Employee processSummaryRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
        employee.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstName"));
        employee.setLastName(rs.getString("lastName"));
        employee.setTitle(rs.getString("title"));
        /*employee.setPicture(rs.getString("picture"));
        employee.setReportCount(rs.getInt("reportCount"));*/
        return employee;
    }
```

}

I have been created the database directory with table name as employee with fields id,firstName,lastName,title.

Now i have the html file in the web-content folder of the **same project** .

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Employee Directory</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <h1>Employee Directory</h1>

    <ul id="employeeList"></ul>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/employeelist.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

employeelist script

```
getEmployeeList();
        function getEmployeeList() {
            $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'employees', function(data) {
                $('#employeeList li').remove();
                var employees = data.employee;
                $.each(employees, function(index, employee) {
                    $('#employeeList').append(
                        '<li><a href="employeedetails.html#' + employee.id + '">'
                        + employee.firstName + ' ' + employee.lastName + ' (' 
                        + employee.title + ')</a></li>');
                });
            });
        }
```

This will shows the extact employee details in the Index page.

Now i have been create an html page in **another project** where i will put same $.getJSON call which specified above will throw error in console as

```
   XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8181/jQueryJAXRS/rest/employees. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Actually I try to develop an application with client and server infrastructure .So i need to have html files in the client to consume the jersey web-services in serverside.It is really helpful if i make $.getJSON or $.ajax call from the html file in another project inorder to consume the web service.

```
when i use this url http://localhost:8181/jQueryJAXRS/rest/employees  in my browser
```

it shows xml

```
<employees>
<employee>
<firstName>john</firstName>
<id>1</id>
<lastName>doe</lastName>
<reportCount>0</reportCount>
<title>trainee</title>
</employee>
<employee>
<firstName>james</firstName>
<id>2</id>
<lastName>dane</lastName>
<reportCount>0</reportCount>
<title>developer</title>
</employee>
<employee>
<firstName>ramsy</firstName>
<id>4</id>
<lastName>stuart</lastName>
<reportCount>0</reportCount>
<title>QA</title>
</employee>
</employees>
```

but when i try through script way it will show CORS error occurs. Suggest some ideas will really help me.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).

For that:

1. You have to use [cors-filter jar](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.thetransactioncompany/cors-filter/1.3.2)
2. Then you have to use a filter in your web.xml :

   ```
   <filter>
   <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
   <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>cors.allowGenericHttpRequests</param-name>
       <param-value>true</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
       <param-value>*</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>cors.allowSubdomains</param-name>
       <param-value>true</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
       <param-value>GET, HEAD, POST, OPTIONS</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
       <param-value>Content-Type, X-Requested-With</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>cors.exposedHeaders</param-name>
       <param-value>X-Test-1, X-Test-2</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>cors.supportsCredentials</param-name>
       <param-value>true</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>cors.maxAge</param-name>
       <param-value>-1</param-value>
   </init-param>
   </filter>


   <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/EmployeeResource</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   ```

Comment: Thanks Jhanvi . I should add the jar in buildpath of the project.Am i right ? Then add these xml as a child of a webapp node in web.xml . Correct me if i go wrong path .

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
<display-name>EmployeeDirectory</display-name><servlet>
<servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
 <init-param>
<param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
<param-value>org.coenraets</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> <filter>yours</filter></webapp> 
NOW getting http status 404 , after CORS jar added

Answer (score 12):

Thanks Jhanvi to suggest this CORS idea. Here i explain more to have a better clarity and make it complete solution for this issue

I refer this link to solve this issue

[CORS JAR](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter-installation.html)

Download the CORS jar and java-property jar.Put those jars in lib folder of tomcat server.Then add the following filter as chlidnode of web-app in web.xml .

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This solution will resolve the CORS issue .

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for this question! It lead me to a shorter way to import the jar by using maven and just adding the dependencies to the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-property-utils</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Check for current versions:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.thetransactioncompany/cors-filter/1.9
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.thetransactioncompany/java-property-utils/1.9

Answer (score 0):

If someone dont want to add third party libraries, they can create their own filters to add required headers in response.
Please refer [How to add CORS support on the server side in Java with Jersey](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-add-cors-support-on-the-server-side-in-java-with-jersey/)