# how can i protect REST Webservice from being hit if used from any tool

Tags: rest

I am using Jersey REST Webservices for my Application which is responsible to show some data present in Database .

The website has got no user registration , so anybody can type the url and see the website .

My worry is that people can see the REST API calls from browser network tab and fire them .

My web service looks somewhat this way

```
package com.services;
@Path("/sgxservice")
public class SGXService {
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String fetchsgxvalue() {

    return "somevalue";
}
}
```

And this is the way i  am making call to the webservice

```
function displaynewsbycompany(enteredtext) {
    var url = 'http://localhost:8080/TradeOnlineChat/rest';
    var s = "";
    url = url + '/sgxservice,
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: false,
            cache: false,
            timeout: 17000,
            async: false,
            jsonpCallback: 'companynews',
           success: function(newsbycompanyresponse) {
               jQuery("#newsbycompanyRss").html("<ul class='feedEkList'>" + s + "</ul>");
            },
            error: function(x, t, m) {
                jQuery(".loadingWrapforlivenews").hide();
            }
        })
        .done(function() {
        });
}
}
```

how can i protect REST Webservice from being hit if used from any tool

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902514/access-control-allow-origin-in-ajax-call-to-jersey-rest-web-services

Comment: that is actually not related to  the question i asked , my query how can i protect the service.

Comment: I protect mine with Origins.  The service must be invoked by my domain.  Direct GET/POST get denied.

Comment: but still i see the issue , if i add CORS suppourt its working from direct browser URL .